# Send parameter to SQL Server stored procedure for Datagridview fill

Tags: sql-server, datagridview

I currently have DATAGRIDVIEW1 bound to a SQL Server stored procedure. It currently returns the entire table. I added a `YEAR` parameter to the select statement in the stored procedure. My VB defaults the year text box to the current year before the

```
Me.GettestsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CW_DataDataSet.gettests)
```

line executes in `Form1_Load`. Can I send the year parameter in this tableadapter fill? Thank you

The form load from VB is as follows.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    yr.Text = Str(Year(Today))

    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CW_DataDataSet.gettests' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.GettestsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CW_DataDataSet.gettests)
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CW_DataDataSet.gettests' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    TextBox1.Text = Str(DataGridView1.RowCount)
    TextBox1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

The SQL Server stored procedure executes:

```
SELECT 
    test_name, test_date, test_qn_result, test_ql_result, 
    test_domain, client_ID
FROM
    testfile
WHERE
    YEAR(test_date) = @YEAR
```

Comment: Procedural code (like stored procedures) is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You might need to re-think how you ask a question in order to receive an appropriate solution to your problem.   I can only assume that you want to know how to get the user's response from the datagridview.  Is that correct?

Comment: I appreciate the guidance.  I am not a regular viewer.  I am using SQL-SERVER.  The stored SQL procedure "gettests" is a simple select procedure.  It very nicely populates DATAGRIDVIEW1 in my VB solution with the entire SQL table.  Due time and space, I added a where statement to the SQL stored procedure using the parameter @INYEAR to get only those rows with activity date during a specific year.  How do I pass this value from VB to the stored procedure ?  I would prefer not to hard code a year in VB so as to give the user some flexibility on what they see in the datagridview.

Comment: Found it...Sorry for the inconvenience.  It merely goes in the Fill statement:  Me.GettestsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CW_DataDataSet.gettests)  becomes  Me.GettestsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CW_DataDataSet.gettests,yrr) where 'yrr' was dimmed as integer and set to th year I want.